# Is there any way to make my query return also empty rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a query to get the number of scheduleds, group by every ten minutes(see below), but when the number of scheduleds in some ten minutes is 0, the query doesnt return nothing, how can i make to return even if its 0.
Returning Example:

```
10  2019-06-01 00:00:00
5   2019-06-01 00:10:00
5   2019-06-01 00:30:00
8   2019-06-01 00:40:00
```

I want to return something like this:

```
10  2019-06-01 00:00:00
5   2019-06-01 00:10:00
0   2019-06-01 00:20:00
5   2019-06-01 00:30:00
8   2019-06-01 00:40:00
```

Heres my query:

```
select count(distinct(s.tracking_uid)) as "Scheduled",
to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from s.created_date) / 600 )) * 600) 
AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' as TenMin
from table.example se 
inner join table.example2 s on s.tracking_uid = se.tracking_uid
where
date(s.created_date) >= '2019/06/01'
and date(s.created_date) < '2019/06/17'
group by TenMin
```

Comment: `distinct` is not a function. Skip those extra parentheses to make the code clearer, i.e. simply do `select count(distinct s.tracking_uid) as "Scheduled", ...`.

Comment: Read about using calendar tables, which is one approach to solve your problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `generate_series()` to generate the values you want:

```
with e as (
      select e.*,
             to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from s.created_date) / 600 )) * 600) at timezone 'UTC' as tz
      from example e
      where s.created_date >= '2019-06-01'::timestamp and
            s.created_date < '2019-06-18'::timestamp
     ) 
select gs.min10, count(distinct e.tracking_id)
from (select generate_series(min(tz), max(tz), interval '10 minute' as min10
      from e
     ) gs left join
     example e
     on e.ts = gs.min10
group by gs.min10
order by gs.min10;
```